# How to show dashed grid line with Vue-ChartjS

Tags: chart.js, vue-chartjs

I'm using [vue-chartjs](https://vue-chartjs.org/), which is recommended in the integration part of the Chart.js documentation.
I want to ask that how to setup the dashed grid line like this.

[image: Demo 1. Dashed on x axis and y axis]

[image: Demo 2. Dashed only o y axis]

I try with

```
options = {
        scales: {
          y: {
            grid: {
              color: this.gridColor,
              tickBorderDash: [1, 5],
              display: true
            },
            ticks: { color: '#2CF1A7', beginAtZero: true, maxRotation: 10 }
          },
          x: {
            grid: {
              color: '#000',
              tickBorderDash: [1, 2],
              display: true
            },
            ticks: { color: '#000', beginAtZero: true }
          }
        }
}
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fl0hs.png)
Only the grid outside show dashed line.

Comment: You have to set `options.scales.x.border.dash` to change the dash of the grid lines perpendicular to x axis. The same with y. I don't understand the logic of this setting, but it *is* [documented](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#border-configuration) as such, so it's presumably not a bug.

Comment: The problem is I can't find the proper documentation for creating dashed line in Vue-Chartjs. It seems like they'are using another configuration schema.  I copy the whole configuration which working perfectly in chartjs but not work on Vue-Chartjs

Comment: I don't know, but by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/tree/main/src) it appears it's a pretty thin wrapper around chart.js. I'd recommend you make a working codesandbox or stackblitz with the relevant part of your code, as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post the link in your question; thus, we can just fork it and start from a concrete example.

Comment: Here is my stackblitz code. Could you take a look at this.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-xbk1iy?file=src%2FchartConfig.ts

Comment: The problem there is the fact that you introduced in the configuration object another `options` level, so it became `options.options.scales.x.border`; also, the option name for the dashed pattern is `dash`, not `dashed`, [stackblitz fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-xbk1iy-n7mwe3?file=src%2FchartConfig.ts)